# Load into CoreData

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, crash, data-persistence

I have created a window based application with the coredata framework included. I have edited my xcdatamodel, created a new entity, defined attributes and generated the managed object class file. When I now try to run my application, my app crashes in the simulator with this error: The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store"; I have no sqlite db in my project. Now my question is how to add data to coredata and get rid of this error! i understand coredata comes with its own db generated at runtime, how can I access that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of this error:
- start the iPhone simulator
- un-install the app by clicking it and holding the mouse button for a few seconds (just like you would uninstall an app on your iPhone)
- re-install + run the app again from XCode

You get this error whenever you changed something in your data model (added attributes / entities etc.). If you want to know how to keep your data when changing the data model, you should google for "CoreData versioning".

Comment: thanks that worked. now when I include a sqlite db in my app bundle with the same name as my project, the coredata methods recognize this as the db to load, but the app still crashes with the same error code. How do I load data from a sqlite database into coredata and edit it? Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: A better way to think of it is "how do I edit data that has been stored in a core data generated schema?". For that you need a sqlite database tool such as SQLite Database Browser.

Comment: You shouldn't have to include your SQLite DB explicitly - CoreData is supposed to manage the SQLite stuff for you. Do you have some existing data in your SQLite DB that you want to import?

Comment: Anyway I figured it out...Frank I will accept your answer, it partially solved my problem.